# Не работает перенаправление в index.php

Tags: php, apache

Всем привет!
Уже целый день мучаюсь, никак не могу понять что не так. Сайт на самописном фрэймворке, c единой точкой входа и своим роутером. Посмотрите пожалуйста что здесь не так, я уже не знаю что думать. Самое странное что на боевом с CentOS и на локальном с виндой все работает как надо, но когда разворачиваешь на тестовом с CentOS начинается проблема. 
 На этом же тестовом сервере другие сайты работают нормально. 
Сервер возвращает 404.

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect to www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.ru$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.ru/$1 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.ru$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.mysite.ru/$1 [L,R=301,NE]


RewriteRule ^cms/$ cms/index.php [L]

RewriteRule media/component/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/(.*) site/components/$1/media/$2 [L]
RewriteRule media/plugin/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/(.*) site/plugins/$1/media/$2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Выяснилась что .htaccess вообще не работает. Может в конфиге виртуального хоста что-то не так?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName mysite.testhost.ru
    ServerAlias www.mysite.testhost.ru
    DocumentRoot /home/stage/hosts/mysite/www
    Include fastcgi56.conf

    <Directory /home/stage/hosts/mysite/www>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Options All -Indexes
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /home/stage/hosts/mysite/log/error.log
    CustomLog /home/stage/hosts/mysite/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: какое из правил не работает? А вообще если на одном сервере работает, а на другом нет, то ищите разницу в настройках серверов.

Comment: Последнее в index.php. К примеру если я перехожу в mysite.ru/shop то перенапровление должно выполнится в index.php но такого не происходит, сразу отдается 404.

Comment: Вы уверены что на тестовом mod_reqwrite включен?

Comment: Да уверен. Другие сайты работают